# Live syntax highlighting in a text field?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, textfield

Many popular sites such as [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) have editors that highlight your code directly as you type them in the text field.

For my own Rails app, I need a plugin that highlights your code as you type it, and supports a handful of languages. How would one quickly create, or use a plugin for this type of highlighting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I heard good things about [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/)